# Adding IK to existing animations

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, unity

I've been doing a character for a Unity game, kinda my first humanoid model/animation so I'm still learning a lot.

I tried IK at the start and gave up because of a bug, then made quite a few animations by hand, but I was having difficulty animating certain things, others took too long, so I decided to add IK properly now that I'm more used to the program.

But adding the IK now messes up the animations, as expected.
My question is, is there any way to make the animations I've already made work with the new IK, or do I have to start from scratch?

Comment: Keyframe the influence of the IK constraint to 0 on those animations?

Comment: I imagine a python script to take the FK rotation animations and apply the end-bone (has IK constraint) location to the IK bone for an approximation.   But I'm too lazy to try...

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you have to redo the animation. With that said, you can always turn IK on before you use it and then turn it off when going back to the other animation. Depending on your existing animation as to which would be easier.

To turn off IK just set influence to 0 on the IK Constraint and with mouse cursor over it press I to keyframe. to turn on set influence to 1. It's a good idea to do a keyframe one frame before you keyframe the change. You can also add a custom property to the control bone and use it as a driver.

This way the option will show on the item tab of the sidebar when you select that bone without having to do python scripting.

Comment: I figured it woulnd't be easy, but needed to know if there was a method around my skill level. 
Anyways, I might just re-do them since there arent so many yet, plus I wasn't satisfied with them for the most part.

Thanks everyone for the inputs!